# Separate compile and linking actions with Bazel

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, bazel

I would like to know if there is a way to execute compiling and linking actions with Bazel in separate steps. If i execute the command

```
bazel build -s //main:hello-world
```

all the bazel SUBCOMMANDS are printed. I am aware that is possible to execute these subcommands from command line, but I would like to know how to use Bazel to execute for instance only the compile action, and only the linking action in separate steps.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: In my case I'd like to disassemble (some) of the object files for analysis. Run them through an objcopy pass. Query by aquery. Too bad it seems all hidden.

Comment: Can you use a genrule() to disassemble which takes as input the output object files of the compilation rule (just_compile) which is decribed below?

Comment: My current idea is having a rule extracting object files from the libraries (`ar x`) and then have rules with those object files as input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are after, but essentially, you can write a custom rule you pass `cc_*` target as a source into and try to pick its actions apart only getting outputs of the ones you are interest in, e.g.:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    outs = []
    for src in ctx.attr.srcs:
        if hasattr(src, "actions"):
            for action in src.actions:
                if action.mnemonic == "CppCompile":
                    outs.append(action.outputs)
    return DefaultInfo(files = depset(transitive = outs))

just_compile = rule(
    _impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(mandatory = True),
    },

)
```

If I then have the following `BUILD` file:

```
load("//:just_compile.bzl", "just_compile")

just_compile(
    name = "compile_hello",
    srcs = [":hello"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.cpp"],
)
```

And you run (you can add `-s` to watch):

```
bazel build compile_hello
```

You will get just the compilation step executed (because we did not actually request `hello` target and there is nothing else needing linking in the tree as requested) and results it produced:

```
bazel-bin/
bazel-bin/_objs
bazel-bin/_objs/hello
bazel-bin/_objs/hello/hello.pic.d
bazel-bin/_objs/hello/hello.pic.o
```

Linking mnemonic is `CppLink`.

So, yes, you can attach yourself to specific actions. And for the sake of debate, this would be at least one option I am aware to do that. But again, I am not entirely sure what exactly are you actually after, what problem are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the compilation pretty easily with a [custom rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html). You'll need to use the [cc_common](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/cc_common.html) APIs to do the normal things that `cc_library` does, but returning all the files in the [DefaultInfo.files](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/DefaultInfo.html#files) [provider](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#providers).

For linking, I'd just use `cc_binary`. You can also do something similar with a custom rule to split out the pieces if you want.

Something like this:

```py
load("@rules_cc//cc:action_names.bzl", "C_COMPILE_ACTION_NAME")
load("@rules_cc//cc:toolchain_utils.bzl", "find_cpp_toolchain")

def _my_c_compile_impl(ctx):
    cc_toolchain = find_cpp_toolchain(ctx)
    source_file = ctx.file.src
    output_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".o")
    feature_configuration = cc_common.configure_features(
        ctx = ctx,
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
        requested_features = ctx.features,
        unsupported_features = DISABLED_FEATURES + ctx.disabled_features,
    )
    _, outputs = cc_common.compile(
        actions = ctx.actions,
        cc_toolchain = cc_toolchain,
        srcs = [source_file],
        name = ctx.label.name,
    )
    return [
        DefaultInfo(files = depset(direct = outputs.objects)),
    ]

my_c_compile = rule(
    implementation = _my_c_compile_impl,
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(mandatory = True, allow_single_file = True),
        "_cc_toolchain": attr.label(default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain")),
    },
    toolchains = ["@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type"],
    incompatible_use_toolchain_transition = True,
    fragments = ["cpp"],
)
```

The rules_cc [my_c_archive example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/examples/my_c_compile/my_c_compile.bzl) is a good starting point if you want to customize things more than `cc_common.compile` allows.

If you want to make this a general debugging tool, you can package similar logic as an [aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) to apply it to arbitrary rules.

For quick debugging, [`--save_temps`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--save_temps) is another technique.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to do compilation and linking in two separate steps with Bazel with the default rules_cc.

The closest what you can get is.

There is a `--nobuild` option thta causes the build to stop before executing the build actions (e.g. compiling, linking, etc.)

You can use `aquery` to query for actions in your build graph.

This will give you similar information as `-s` does, but without actually calling the commands.

Another approach could be to come up with own rules, e.g.

```
cc_binary_compilation(
    name = "...",
    srcs = [...]
)

cc_binary_linking(...)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, for you answer. D you know, if would also possible to excute the compilation and linking in two separate steps through Bazel? For the moment, the only way i can do it is by re-executing the SUBCOMMANDS from command line, but this doesn't require to use Bazel.

Comment: Or alternatively, also a way to execute the subcommands one by one from command line, after executing the Bazel build with --nobuild option would be helpful. For the moment i can only re-execute the commands after a succesfull and complete build, but not executing them one by one after a --nobuild excution. I get an error "env: bazel/toolchains/mingw: No such file or directory" even if this directory is present in my workspace.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do compilation and linking in two separate steps with Bazel with the default rules_cc.

Comment: I see, in th end i had to use the implementation of own rules and that worked. Tanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify to only receive a certain output group.
So to look at what output groups there are use:

`bazel cquery  //my_target --output=starlark --starlark:expr="[str(og) for og in target.output_groups]"`

Then to build only that output group this one is for c++ compilation only (no link):

`bazel build //my_target --output_groups=compilation_outputs`

The trick is to not use `+` or `-` in the `output_groups` this modifies the default output group.